# Как правильно записать данные в поля? (котлин, андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin

Как всё таки правильно записывать данные в поля по функции. Одно активити, два фрагмента. Поля находятся во фрагменте №1.
Стираются так - `date2?.text?.clear()`, но так не записываются - `date2?.text? = "12.12.2012"`. А записываются только так `date1?.setText("12.12.2012")`
Кратко код такой (фрагмент 1):

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

public var date1: EditText? = null
public var date2: EditText? = null
.............................
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...............................
date1 = binding.fieldDate1
date2 = binding.fieldDate2
.......................
binding.btnFill.setOnClickListener {
    fillAlldate()
}
```

В файле MyFunc.kt

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType", "SetTextI18n")
fun FirstFragment.fillAlldate() {
    date1?.setText("4984")
    date2?.text?.clear()
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос - так уж язык устроен. На Nullable ссылках не применить синтаксический сахар. По идее, должно вот так сработать: `date2!!.text = "12.12.2012"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб правильно поняли. Но не сработало. Дополнил вопрос скриншотом gif. Там видны описания ошибок. Может мне вообще null с полей убрать? Сделал `public lateinit var date4: EditText` и `date4.text = "27.10.2015"` - всё равно подчеркивает красным строку. Опять тип кажется не нравится

Comment: Ага... А если как-то так? `date2!!.text = "test" as Editable`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы поняли в чем дело). `Основной метод класса EditText — getText(), который возвращает текст, содержащийся в текстовом поле. Возвращаемое значение имеет специальный тип Editable, а не String.` Но в данном случае в коде слово `AS` выделяется желтым цветом с комментарием `"This cast can never succeed"` и программа вылетает при попытке занести это значение. Ошибка `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.Editable` (строка не может быть преобразована в текст). И для установки текста используется метод setText().

Comment: В Андроиде правильно держать все строки в ресурсах, оттуда и записывать.

Comment: В данном случае вопрос имеет теоретическое значение для изучения теории котлина и андроид студии.Да и в ресурсах этих значений не будет, потому что они формируются динамически. Как то так. По факту и получается и данные записываются в ресурсы